# Vim go into insert mode when as a macro starts

Tags: vimrc

When doing `<ESC>qq` you can record a macro into the `q` register (still in command mode though). How can I make `<ESC>qq` go into insert mode right away (without having to type `i`)? `map qq qqi` will record and put me into insert mode, but I am unable to replay with `@@` or `@q`. The docs say you cannot use the `q` command inside a macro, but it does not specify what happens in my case.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Yes, a macro needs to begin and end in normal mode. Perhaps what you want is a mapping instead? If you share more details of the specific problem you want to solve, it might be easier to give you good suggestions.

Comment: Simply dont want to type the extra character if there is a way to get around it (also, forget to go into insert mode sometimes). When mapping `qq` to `qqi`, it doest work the same as just typing `qqi` like normal

Comment: Yeah... But what exactly do you want to do with macros in insert mode? Can you give a specific example of what you'd use that for?

Comment: Usually when I am making a macro, it starts off with me typing in insert mode (adding headers or brackets and such), then going into command mode, etc. Is it impossible for a map to go into a macro, switch modes, then end?

Comment: A macro will always end in normal mode, since you need to type the command `q` in normal mode to end it. Furthermore, a macro can only be called from normal mode, since the `@` command is a normal mode command as well. Perhaps what you want is a `inoremap` or a `iabbrev`? If you can ask the question more specifically (such as "how can I have this key sequence in insert mode expand to this text, with headers and brackets?" and add an example of what it looks before and after), it would be much easier to give you a good answer.

Comment: Also consider that Vim is more effective if you spend more time in normal mode rather than insert... You should only be in insert mode while inserting text, but use normal for navigation and commands that apply transformations to your text. (perhaps that's why macros are a normal mode thing.)

Comment: `inoremap` and `iabbrev` didnt do the trick, but Id agree and say its probably best to just type it out. Say the cursor isnt positioned before I start the macro, then I would have to hit <ESC> and move it again anyways. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As filbranden mentions, [edit]ing to clarify your question would be helpful—I think we’re in a bit of an XY problem situation here. It sounds like you may have a use case for snippets or templates, but it’s really quite hard to tell what your true goal is (because we’re hung up on this macro/insert mode thing). Again, as @filbranden says, macros must start and end in normal mode (and normal mode rocks). Consider [edit]ing your question to describe your real goals